# How to join two tables from different databases with petl

Tags: python, petl

I am using petl python package to perform some queries on tables that are stored in SQL Server databases. I need now to do a `JOIN` between 2 tables that are on different databases.

The function `petl.fromdb` only accepts, as far as I know, one connection `[petl.fromdb(connection, query)]`.

Any ideas whether it is possible to do what I am trying with petl? If not, is there any package that allows me to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You may read both tables from their databases separately and then join them using `petl.join()`:

```
import petl as etl

# Read both tables
table_a = etl.fromdb(connection_a, 'SELECT * FROM table_a')
table_b = etl.fromdb(connection_b, 'SELECT * FROM table_b')

# Join tables into new table
table_c = etl.join(table_a, table_b, key='id')
```

For details on `petl.join()` see the [documentation](https://petl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/transform.html#joins).